# Что значит кубит в терминологии квантового компьютера?

Tags: терминология

Что значит "кубит" в терминологии квантового компьютера?

Comment: Википедию читали? Какие вопросы остались?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov: что конкретно вас раздражает?

Comment: Меня ничего не раздражает. Я хочу узнать, что именно Вам не понятно?

Comment: Вполне ясный вопрос. Не можете или не хотите отвечать, не надо сеять какое-то "пренебрежение" к моему вопросу.

Comment: Либо скажите, что не так в вопросе, либо пройдите мимо.

Comment: В очередной раз, читая в https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80 `Один кубит можно представить в виде электрона в двухъямном потенциале, так что | 0 ⟩  означает нахождение его в левой яме, а | 1 ⟩   — в правой. Это называется кубит на зарядовых состояниях.` убедился, что абсолютно не представляю, как можно программировать такую железку -)

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, кубит это минимальное количество *квантовой информации* (а вот как этим пользоваться, я к своему стыду не  понимаю)

Comment: @avp: когда-то в школе мне не понятен был бит, размышляя о кубите я вспоминаю то странное чувство.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не соответствует тематике сайта

Comment: Чую, сейчас закроют. Многовато тут участников, которые не приемлют то, чего не знают. / Наверное бит стал понятен, когда вы поняли, как ими кодируются числа, с которыми вы уже умели управляться (арифметика). Наверное некоторые физики умеют управляться с наборами квантовых объектов и вот им (наверное) что такое кубит кажется очевидным. / Подозреваю, что нам для понимания тоже надо поучиться квантовой физике и соответствующему мат. аппарату.

Comment: Кстати, м.б. читали [Квантовый компьютер: взлом любого шифра, кубиты и крайне низкие температуры](https://geektimes.ru/company/mailru/blog/278070/), конечно, суть дела не проясняет, но интересно рассказывает, как это может выглядеть технологически

Comment: Вопрос соответствует тематике сайта, он про программирование на новых типах компьютерах -- квантовых. Может мы уже через пять лет будем учить новые языки программирования, вполне можно уже готовиться и учить матчасть. Если бы нашёлся некто, кто коротко бы дал ответ -- было бы вполне неплохо. Предлагаю оставить.

Answer (score 2):

[Источник](https://geektimes.ru/company/mailru/blog/278070/)

> Кубиты — квантовые биты — такие же элементарные блоки квантового процессора, как транзисторы в процессорах обычных компьютеров. Нужно различать теоретическое понятие кубита, как единицы квантовой информации, и физическое воплощение кубитов, для которого могут быть использованы различные физические системы — фотоны, ионы, спины ядер и электронов. Сегодня больше всего надежд возлагается на сверхпроводящие кубиты.
>
> Но как работает кубит? Всем нам знакомы биты — нули и единички, которые обрабатываются обычными компьютерами. Квантовые биты очень на них похожи (хотя и не без квантовых странностей). У них тоже есть два основных состояния — 0 и 1, но, благодаря особому квантовому свойству — суперпозиции — они могут находиться в любом из состояний между нулем и единичкой.

Answer (score 0):

Кубит - то же, что и классический бит, минимальное значение информации условно равное 0 или 1. Принципиальное различие от стандартного транзисторного процессора: в транзисторном процессоре регистрируется наличие или отсутствие напряжения транзистора, а в квантовом планируется регистрировать положение частицы.

Причем пока точно не известно какое именно положение частицы будет регистрироваться и какая это будет частица: может это будет фотон, может электрон и т.д. В интернете много баек на этот счет якобы с одновременным нахождением кубита в 2-ух местах, это как пнуть мяч и он сразу станет представлять из себя 2 мяча в разных точках футбольного поля, только это будет один и тот же мяч (если что-то подобное и есть, то этому может быть вполне логичное объяснение, например, волна). Но чудес в природе как известно пока не существует, разве что при ядерных реакциях.

Тем не менее, если и создадут квантовый компьютер - то это будет революция.

Comment: Так работают же уже квантовые алгоритмы. На мелких задачах пока, но пруфофворк есть.

Comment: И что значит, не известно какая будет частица? На каких частицах собрали, та и будет.

Comment: @vp_arth То, что они работают - сильно сказано, 2-3 кубита, это все эксперименты, каким образом реально это будет работать пока никто не знает (по крайней мере в открытом доступе). Согласно википедии частица кубита - это фотон, но ничто не мешает закодировать электрон, протон или что-то еще. Многое из того, что сейчас преподносится на эту тему - заказные статьи из области фантастики.